# Excel 2016: find most current date in a row then return column header

Tags: microsoft-excel, headers

[image]

What is the formula to find most current date in a row and return it's column header. For example, per below:
  - BLUE: cell C242 returned 75%CD by searching for most current date in that row (9/1/2016) and returning that column header title "75%CD)
  - ORANGE: cell C244 returned RFIs be searching most current date in the row (8/11/2016) and returning that column header title "RFIs"

PLEASE NOTE: most current date might be at the beginning, or in the middle, or at the end of the row. Searching for first or last non-zero value won't work....

Thank you for your help

Comment: Why do you expect a result of "75%CD" for row 242 and not "75%CD Volume 1 Reissued"? (You do want cell C242 to display the header from L7, right?)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the latest date is always in the "received" column, you could use

```
=INDEX($H$7:$M$7,MATCH(MAX(H9:M9),H9:M9,0)-1)
```

The merged cells provide a potential issue, since the text value is stored in columns H, J and L, whereas the matched date is in columns I, K or M. Hence I subtract 1 from the match returned.

If the matched date can also be in the "issued" column, I suggest you insert a row between 7 and 8, and enter the text from row 7 into all cells, without mergin. Then you can return the text from that row without correcting the match.